# Update ecs agent permanently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to update `ecs container agent` described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/agent-update-ecs-ami.html

I did essentially

```
sudo yum update -y ecs-init
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Agent seems to be upgraded , so far so good.

However when a new instance is created (for autoscale group or whatever reason), the agent associated with the new instance seems to be still the old version.

How can I permanently update `ecs container agent`?

Comment: Either use an AMI that includes the updated version, or do the upgrade in the user-data script.

Comment: @jordanm would I add those two lines in the user-data script? does putting `sudo systemctl restart docker` seem fine ?

Comment: Yeah, but you may also need to add a command to start the ecs-agent after restarting docker

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using the latest ami in your asg config, the last ami release always contains the latest ecs agent. afaik - the agent releases happen via ami releases.

`aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/recommended` can be used to retrieve the latest al2 ecs ami. [check these ecs ami docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html#ecs-optimized-ami-linux)